# Finding constants in intial value problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have some problems in determining constants in initial value problems, especially for linear nonhomogenous differential equations.

Use this as an example:

$$x'(t) = 2t - 2x(t) + 5, x(0) = -1$$

We are basically allowed to simply solve these by using the formula for nonhomogenous ODEs:

$$ y = (\int_0^t b(t)e^{A(t)} dt + c)e^{-A(t)}$$

So in this case I have: $a(t) = 2, b(t) = 2t + 5$

and therefore:

$$y = (\int_0^t(2t+5)e^{2t} dt + c)e^{-2t}$$

for which I get:

$$y=(\frac{1}{2}e^{2t}(2t-1)+\frac{1}{2}e^0 + \frac{5}{2}e^{2t}-\frac{5}{2}+c)e^{-2t}$$

$$y = t-2e^{-2t}+2+ce^{-2t}$$

Now what value should the constant take?

First of all is it correct to simply carry the c "with me" in the calculations? I know that ultimately the first c comes from the integration of $a(t)$, then after the term in the braces is integrated, that c changes. So if I get this term in the end:

$$y = t-2e^{-2t}+2+ce^{-2t}$$

Can I simply determine c by plugging in $t=0$ and setting the value of that expression equal to -1?

$$y(0)=0-2e^0+2+ce^0=-1$$

And then solve for c? Would that be correct?

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same with the difference that due to the integrating that you would have to do, you'd have to probably take more time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:** Use your approach (you have a calculation issue).

$$x(t) = \left(\int_0^t b(t)e^{at} dt + c\right)e^{-at} = \left(\left(\int_0^t (2t+5)e^{2t} dt\right) + c\right)e^{-2t}$$

This results in:

$$x(t) = \left((e^{2 t} (t+2)-2) + c\right)e^{-2t} = t + 2 + (c - 2)e^{-2 t}$$

Now we use the initial condition and arrive at $c = -1$, to yield:

$$x(t) = t + 2 -3 e^{- 2t}$$

However, I would say the following method is preferred over this approach.

**Method 2:** Integrating Factor

Here we have $x'(t) + 2 x = 2t + 5$, so the IF is:

$$\mu(t) = e^{\int 2t dt} = e^{2 t}$$

This yields the same result as above.

Other methods are also possible like using an Exact Equation, Laplace Transform, ...